# HashMap: get Key-Value by key during onClick event (Frame)

Tags: java, hashmap, itemlistener

Need some advice please.
I'm parsing xml and put some data from it to a HashMap.
**Please, take a look at a piece of code:**

```
final HashMap<String,String> urls = new HashMap<String,String>();
* * *
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Row");                       
        for (int z=0; z<nList.getLength(); z++) {
        Node nNode = nList.item(z);
        Element eElement = (Element) nNode; 

        NodeList a = eElement.getElementsByTagName("item");
        for (int i=0; i<a.getLength(); i++) {                               
            urls.clear();
            String b = eElement.getElementsByTagName("item").item(i).getTextContent();
            String c = eElement.getElementsByTagName("url").item(i).getTextContent();           
            urls.put(b, c);
            System.out.println(urls);                       
                }
            }
```

So, I've got this pairs:

```
{Select product=bla-bla-bla} 
{Single Landmine Shirt=/www.sample.com/landmine-single-shirt} 
{Women's Silver & Black Bar=/www.sample.com/womens-silver-and-black-bar}                         
{High Density Foam Rollers=/www.sample.com/high-density-foam-rollers}
```

Now I 'd like to print key value (Url of product) by key(Product), while I'm selecting a corresponding item from d-down List.

```
    /*comboBox:*/ addProduct.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            String s = String.valueOf(addProduct.getSelectedItem());
            if ((e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) && (urls.containsKey(s))) {

            Object v = (String) urls.get(s);    
            System.out.println("Your url: " + v.toString());
            } 
        }       

    });
```

IDK what I'm doing wrong, but when I'm just adding simple Strings to Map: **urls.put("Select product", "test Url");** -> All works good.
Please advice how to deal with it.
Will be glad for any answers

Comment: What is the output you're getting? Note that you do not need to cast to `String` if you're going to assign to an `Object`. `urls.get(s)` already returns a String, why not print it without assigning it ?

Comment: @YassinHajaj, could you please provide a code update here?

Comment: `System.out.println("Your url is : " + urls.get(s))` ... Still my question remains unanswered, what is your output? Are you sure urls is filled?

Comment: @YassinHajaj, Yes. It's filled.
Output is like this:
{Select product=bla-bla-bla}
{Single Landmine Shirt=http://www.sample.com/landmine-single-shirt}
{Women's Silver & Black Bar=http://www.sample.com/womens-silver-and-black-bar}
{High Density Foam Rollers=http://www.sample.com/high-density-foam-rollers}
{Sling Shot Hogan Wraps=http://www.sample.com/sling-shot-hogan-wraps}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are aware of the fact that you're clearing your `HashMap` on each iteration. This means that your `HashMap` will end containing one and only element : the last `item` tag's data.

```
for (int i=0; i<a.getLength(); i++) {                               
    urls.clear();
    // ...
}
```

Get rid of this line and your `urls` should be filled correctly.

Comment: Thank you. Now looks much better

Comment: I've got one more question.
    urls.clear(); -> this is done for correct view of my key-value pairs.
there are for { } cycle, and my data are mixed wrongly.
like this:
{Single Landmine Shirt=http://www.sample.com/landmine-single-shirt, Select product=bla-bla-bla}
{Women's Silver & Black Bar=http://www.sample.com/womens-silver-and-black-bar, Single Landmine Shirt=http://www.sample.com/landmine-single-shirt, Select product=bla-bla-bla}

Comment: @EvgEvg Please post a new question if you have another question, I'll answer it with pleasure.